# How to launch a .bat file to run separately from Powershell (pt1 of a 2pt problem)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, 3dsmax

I have a `.bat` file that will sit in a folder and open all files of a certain extension when double clicked on (in this case 3dsMax).

I want to create a GUI for powershell (or possibly python) that when opened, I can insert the location of the file and have a button that launches the `.bat` file in that location.

I have tried many different codes I have found on here and other site such as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call.......

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen.......

os.system.....

Start-Process....
```

Even just the location of the .bat file.

The closest I have got is to make the `.bat` file run, but it opens the 3dsmax file running through all the load process in Powershell or CMD.
Then 3dsmax tries to open the UI and I end up with 400+ versions of max trying to open and it crashes. (Edit - 400+ versions of just the one file it's trying to open).

I don't want to change the .bat file as it works nicely and does more than just open the .max file.
I just need it to open the file normally outside of CMD or any shell.

Thanks in advance

(Edit) .bat file code below..

```
for /r %%v in (*.max) do (
  start "" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\3ds Max 2018\3dsmax.exe" -u MAXScript Wire_colorizer_0.ms %%v 
)
```

Comment: You have a script that opens all 3dsMax files when you run it, and you want to run the script but you don't want the 3dsMax files to open when you do that? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: What I mean is when powershell runs the .bat file, all the loading etc is visible in CMD or powershell and it tried to open 100's of max windows when there is just one max file in the folder.
I need it to open just the one per .max file.

My concern is there is a repeat going on and or the .bat function is being brought in and run in the powershell or CMD or something?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the batch code that you're using

Comment: ok - will edit again sorry. I just tried to avoid that being altered.

Comment: Ok, try this for science: `Set-Location "C:\path\to\bat"` and then `Start-Process "C:\path\to\bat\name.bat"`.

Comment: Sorry but if you want to write a PowerShell or Python script, throw away that batch file and just do it in that new script. It's a no-brainer-one-liner in any script language I can think of.

Comment: Yeah great mate, that worked! 
(I'm brand new to code etc can you tell) 

My next issue is creating a GUI that has two fields, that when filled in change a folder name in the location IE
"C:\path\to\bat\name.bat"
Field one "A"
Field two "B"
Click button will now run "C:\path\A\B\name.bat"

I am creating the GUI in PoshGUI but I don't know the code to be able to have fields add folder names into the path of the final code that runs..

Thanks so much again nemze!!

Comment: Hi, Clijsters, Cheers

I did think could be a way of doing it, but the folder location, .max file name, and the script in the batch file will change each time.
And I wanted a non-coding non 3D person to be able to put in the location folders and click run and it do what it needs to with no more input than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want solution with A and B field, but there you go:

```
function startBAT() {
    $STARTButton.Enabled = $false #disable START button, so u won't accidentally run it again while executing
    Set-Location "C:\something\$($TextBox.text)\$($TextBox2.text)" #textbox.text = field A, textbox2.text = field B
    Start-Process "C:\something\$($TextBox.text)\$($TextBox2.text)\name.bat"
    $STARTButton.Enabled = $true #enable START button after done
    $form.Close() #close GUI immediately after execution, delete this line if you dont want to
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = '500,230'
$Form.text = "Lunch .bat file from location"
$Form.TopMost = $false
$Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false

$Label = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.text = "Field A:"
$Label.AutoSize = $true
$Label.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,30)
$Label.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,50)
$Label.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox.multiline = $false
$TextBox.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,50)
$TextBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,50)
$TextBox.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Label2 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.text = "Field B:"
$Label2.AutoSize = $true
$Label2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,90)
$Label2.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,80)
$Label2.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox2 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox2.multiline = $false
$TextBox2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,110)
$TextBox2.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,50)
$TextBox2.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$STARTButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$STARTButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,150)
$STARTButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$STARTButton.Text = 'START'
$STARTButton.Add_Click({startBAT}) 

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label, $TextBox,$Label2, $TextBox2, $STARTButton))

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Also in your batch scritpt, you are using `/r` parameter, so it will run every file in entered path and its subfolders. If you want to run it only for files in entered folder path (without subfolders), just delete `/r` from your `.bat` script.

Comment: Ah thats amazing mate thanks.
The reason I wanted A & B fields is because all the "A" projects sit on the same drive in the same folder, but there can be multiple "B" folder inside them containing the .max files.
With this GUI someone can stipulate Folder A containing folder B on that drive and it will run whatever .bat file is in there.
Appreciate the time and effort on this mate. I only started looking at CMD and Powershell and MaxScript last week so its mostly Egyptian to me at the moment.